# Cypress cy.route2 doesn't catch the request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I have a login page, that I want to test with Cypress and I want to utilize the dynamic response feature from the new `route2` function. My original test with `cy.route()` works:

```js
 cy.server();
 cy.route({method: 'POST', url: '/api/login', status: 401, response: {
   code: 401,
   message: "Invalid credentials"
 }}).as('login_xhr');
```

But the `cy.route2()` not:

```js
        cy.route2('/api/login',  {
                statusCode: 401, 
                body: {
                    code: 401,
                    message: "Invalid credentials"
                }
            }).as('login_xhr');
```

What am I doing here wrong? the rest of the check looks like this for both cases:

```js
cy.get('.tab-pane.active input[name="email"]').type('test@exmaple.com');
        cy.get('.tab-pane.active input[name="password"]').type('wrong_pw');
        
        cy.contains('button', 'Login').click();
        cy.wait('@login_xhr');
```

Also with `cy.route2()` the request is aborted:

[image]

Comment: Do you maybe need to specify the method i.e. ''POST" when you call cy.route2()?

Comment: I tried that one also, just simply posted this one here. Originally it was route2({method: 'post', url: '/api/login}, { ...